# Load all Appointment Properties, including extended properties, in Exchange 2010

Tags: api, calendar, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I'm trying to list all the properties associated with a given calendar appointment, but I can't figure out if there's a way to do it without loading each property individually. Based on some of the code I've seen online, I know I can do something like the following:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// List all the properties of an appointment
    /// </summary>
    public void listProps()
    {
        Folder myCalendar = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);
        ItemView view = new ItemView(10);
        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;

        do
        {
            findResults = myCalendar.FindItems(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ItemSchema.ExtendedProperties, MyPropertySetId), view);
            service.LoadPropertiesForItems(findResults, new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Subject, ItemSchema.Body));

            foreach (Item item in findResults)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Body);
            }

            if (findResults.NextPageOffset.HasValue)
            {
                view.Offset = findResults.NextPageOffset.Value;
            }

        } while (findResults.MoreAvailable);
    }
```

However, what I'm really looking for there in the middle is something like this pseudo code:

```
             service.LoadPropertiesForItems(findResults, new PropertySet(*.*));

             foreach (Item item in findResults)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(property)
             }
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

You can use predefined property sets like: `PropertySet.FirstClassProperties` to get the known set of properties.

Getting extended properties this way is not supported at all. You have to specify explicitly which extended properties you want to access. For example:

```
ItemView view = new ItemView(10);

ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedPropertyDefinition =
new ExtendedPropertyDefinition("Expiration Date", MapiPropertyType.String);

view.PropertySet = 
new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.Subject,extendedPropertyDefinition);
```